# Twitter api + OAuth 'random' 401 error

Tags: oauth, twitter

I have just switch to OAuth

I'm using

- the OAuth exemple code from http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2009/03/twitter-oauth-with-net/
- single user token [link text](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_single_token)
- accounts are set to read-write( I'm testing with 3 account : test , news and jobs)
- I have configured my subdomain also

Test works fine, news never works, jobs works sometimes

when it fails I get an error 401 Unauthorized.

I did try to delete and recreate the applications

My main issue is why does it work sometimes and not other times? Is it my mistake or is twitter having issues.

An other issue that might not be related, when I look at my tweet, I don't see the same tweets if I'm logged in or not.

Comment: When does it not work? Does it not work for specific API methods? Is it consistant? What error message does Twitter return in the body of the 401 response?